# How can I fix Purple Screen of Death for ESX 5.5?

Tags: vmware-esxi, hp, server-crashes, hp-proliant

I have a ESX 5.5 installed on my HP Proliant DL 180 G6 with a configuration of 
8X Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5540  @ 2.53GHz, 24 Gb RAM.

Recently the server has crashed four times, showing the [Purple Screen of Death](http://searchvmware.techtarget.com/definition/Purple-Screen-of-Death-PSOD).
Once this happens all of the virtual machines on the server stops and crashes until I restart this server.

I don't exactly know what causes this error, is it hardware problem?

Update: I forgot to mention that the operating system is 5.5 Update 1 
and this is the image of the error

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[By upgrading to at least ESX 5.5 Update 1](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2059053).

Alternately, this is caused by guests with E1000 network adapters, so if updating isn't possible, or not possible immediately, you can always change the vNIC adapter type on the guests.

Of course, there is the off chance that this PSOD is caused by something else, but since you haven't posted any error log information, it's impossible to verify that your PSOD issue is the same one the rest of the world has been having with ESXi 5.x.  [And, on that off chance, here's the VMware kb article on interpreting PSOD screens](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1004250).

Answer (score 3):

It *could* be a hardware issue, but probably more of a firmware thing. Can you ensure that your firmware is [up-to-date](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?sp4ts.oid=3884342&swItemId=MTX_57c69323072044e8a0789abda9&swEnvOid=4103#tab-history) on the host server?

The other thing to do is update your ESXi host. Your build number is: 1623387. The *current* build number is [2302651](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2096281).

Many people don't understand that [VMware actually needs to be patched and updated](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/6195/im-tired-of-answering-questions-with-upgrade-the-firmware-or-run-updates). The process is [not difficult](https://communities.vmware.com/people/vmroyale/blog/2011/09/15/updating-esxi-5--single-use-esxcli-how-to), but it's what I'd try in your situation.

It may be easier to open up a VMware support ticket, since this could be multiple issues. See [this](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2075978) or [this](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?sp4ts.oid=5193137&docId=emr_na-c03543898&lang=en&cc=th).

Answer (score 1):

This was probably firmware or driver issue. Please update your host to latest firmwares with SPP(Service Pack for Proliant.)

Most probably about HPSA driver. please check out kb below.

http://kb.vmware.com/kb/2075978

Answer (score 0):

Only solution is to restart or reboot the System.

Most PSOD is created by Hardware Failures so check the Hardware Settings properly.

If possible try this:

In BIOS, under HP Power Regulator, use HP Static High Performance Mode.
And add VMware boot flag timerEnableTSC = false
Add VMware boot flag usePCC = false

Answer (score -1):

This is not only related to firmware of patch. sometimes its also related to the processor issue. below is the link for the vmware Knowledge base that explains it all.

http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1004250